# NPE when analysing project in Eclipse (SonarQube 5.2)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I updated from SonarQube 5.1.2 to 5.2.

In Eclipse I start analysis with SonarQube with the latest plugin version. But a dialog pops up saying there is a NPE. The Eclipse error log displays:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.wsclient.internal.SonarWSClientFacade.getUnresolvedRemoteIssuesRecursively(SonarWSClientFacade.java:170)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.remote.RemoteSourceCode.getRemoteIssuesRecursively(RemoteSourceCode.java:107)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.doRefreshIssues(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:131)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.fetchRemoteIssues(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:120)
    at org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.run(SynchronizeAllIssuesJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

What is the problem? How can I make analysis in Eclipse work with SonarQube 5.2?

Comment: What is your version of SonarQube Eclipse plugin?

Comment: SonarQube Eclipse plugin version 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE and Eclipse version 4.5.1.

Comment: Please try with latest LTS version (4.5.6).

Comment: Why try with SonarQube 4.5.6 when I said it works with 5.1.2 but not with 5.2? Does that info really help you (since it is quite some effort to install it and run the analysis again for that project)?

Comment: Sorry I was probably tired :) or I mixed with another thread. So indeed no need to test with LTS.

Comment: Any updates on how you got it fixed..

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use Eclipse SonarQube Plugin with SonarQube 5.2 or newer.

---

From [SonarQube Wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse):

> **The SonarQube Eclipse plugin is deprecated**
>
> The SonarQube Eclipse plugin does not work with SonarQube 5.2+. It is replaced by [SonarLint for Eclipse](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/).
>
> Note that SonarLint for Eclipse 1.x series do not cover yet all the features of SonarQube Eclipse plugin, but versions 2.x will definitely cover this gap.

Comment: lolwut?! the sonar lint currently doesn't support connecting to a sonar instance nor any kind of rule customization

Comment: SonarLint 2.0 allows to connect to the SonarQube server. Read more at http://www.sonarsource.com/2016/04/06/sonarlint-for-eclipse-2-0-released/