# Unable to configure SonarQube with Eclipse (Neon)

Tags: java, eclipse, server, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I did following steps.

1. Eclipse > Install new software > http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/ 
   installed SonarQube.
2. Run the bat file >StartSonar.bat
   (Version: sonarqube-6.6 )
3. Eclipse > Window > Preferences > SonarQube > Server 
   Click the edit and entered "admin" password.
   Tested connection success.
4. http://localhost:9000/projects also work. Logged using "admin" password.
5. Created new java class on eclipse. (Ex: HelloWold class )
6. Right clicked project and > Configure >Associate with sonarQube

Window is loaded. In the project panel, my project name is displayed there. But nothing drop down in "SonarQube Project" panel. Even though I typed something (Simple java, Java, etc.) nothing listed. No result display. I'm new to here. I was unable to find out any solution which was described previously. Appreciate any of your help.

Comment: Try accessing the SonarQube related windows using the quick access, I was never able to find them by searching, so just press Ctrl+3 or click on the Quick Access bar and type sonar you should see the configuration. There you can link to your servers as expected

Comment: similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972656/4944847

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SonarQube Eclipse plugin has been deprecated, and won't work with the version of SonarQube that you are using (6.6).

See https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse

> The SonarQube Eclipse plugin is deprecated
>
> **The SonarQube Eclipse plugin does not work with SonarQube 5.2+.** It is replaced by SonarLint for Eclipse.

This is where you can get SonarLint: https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html